# Phonegap 2.3 error calling method on NPObject when post to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I just updated Phonegap, and I found there is a problem occurred.

There is an api used for posting message to Facebook, it works on PhoneGap2.2, but error occurs on PhoneGap 2.3.

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: link,
    picture: picture,
    name: name,
    description: description,
    redirect_uri: 'http://facebook.com'
};
function callback(response) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}
if (!isFbInit) {
    FB.init({
        appId: "...",
        status: true,
        cookie: true
    });
    isFbInit = true;
}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Error Message:

> Uncaught Error:Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/lib/cordova/cordova-2.3.0.js:1062
>
> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

By the way, my device is Android.

Is this PhoneGap's problem? Could I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you whitelist facebook.com?

Comment: <access origin=".*"/> in config.xml still not work